# Mobile Browser and HTTP Compression (gzip)

Tags: http, browser, mobile, compression, gzip

Which web browsers on **mobile** devices don't support HTTP Compression? Specifically **GZIP**?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a list and this isn't tracked by the like of WURFL, et al.

Rather than working from a predefined list of devices, detect this on a case by case basis depending on the support declared in the HTTP headers.